# talend - tReplicate -> tMap -> tUnite

Tags: talend

I'm trying to query only once, and after that produce two entry on the output file (their mapping for retrieving of fields are different but it corresponds to the same number of output).

Here is the flow that I'm aiming:

```
                         tMap1 
                         /   \ 
tOracleInput -> tReplicate   tUnite - tSort - tOutputFile
                         \   /
                          tMap2
```

But its not allowing me to connect tMap2 to tUnite (if tMap2 to another tOutputFile is okay).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can not use tReplicate and tUnite in the same subjob. What you can do here is:

```
                             tOutputFile    
                             /
tOracleInput -> tSort -->tMap -- > tOutputFile
```

You can keep your output file in append mode. so that you will get a single output and also you dont have to use tReplicate, instead you can have multiple output flow in tMap only.

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the feature you are looking for is `tSplitRow`.

It lets you split one input row into one or more output rows, out of the same stream.

Read here:
https://help.talend.com/reader/wDRBNUuxk629sNcI0dNYaA/yn7aPyanBrstCYkH_XhyIw